# Possible bug in android?

Tags: java, android, list

I guess that for some reason, the program below is passing by through conditions verifications and executing next condition's lines...

This program of mine should add the values 4 and 0 to the `listIntercedeOut`, but it removes right after adding them to the list...

- If we put an empty `for()` right after the `listIntercedeOut.add()` methods, it doesn't remove 
  after...
- Also, if we disable both `listIntercedeOut.remove()` lines commented on the code, the code works either...

I've made a little interface with TextView and Button to check list's values, I've made a lot of modifications from my main program... Those "almost-empty" conditions are needed there...

Also, that `intercede(boolean)` method will always return true in the example.

AddDisciplina.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AddDisciplina extends AppCompatActivity {

Button buttonCheck;

TextView text;

private List<Integer> listIntercedeIn = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Integer> listIntercedeOut = new ArrayList<>();
private SparseArray<String> sparseSeg=new SparseArray<>();

String time = "00:00";
String time2 = "01:30";
int var = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_add_disciplina);
    if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    buttonCheck = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCheck);
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

    buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String items="";
            for(int i = 0; i < listIntercedeOut.size(); i++){
                items = items + "-" + String.valueOf(listIntercedeOut.get(i));
            }
            text.setText(items);
        }
    });
    sparseSeg.put(0, "01:00/02:00");
    sparseSeg.put(4, "00:00/01:30");
    abrirTimePicker(false);
}

private void abrirTimePicker(final boolean inicio){
    if(inicio) {
        if (time.equals("")) {
        }
    } else {
        if((1<0)||(1==0 && 30<=0)){
        }
        switch (var){
            case 3:
                for (int i = 0; i < sparseSeg.size(); i++) {
                String[] hs = sparseSeg.valueAt(i).split("/");
                int idDoLL = sparseSeg.keyAt(i);
                if ((inicio && !hs[1].equals("vazio") && intercede(hs[0], hs[1], time, time2)) ||
                        (!inicio && !hs[1].equals("vazio") && intercede(time, time2, hs[0], hs[1]))) {
                    if (inicio) { // DO SOMETHING
                    } else {
                        // SHOULD ALWAYS END HERE //
                        listIntercedeOut.add(4);
                        listIntercedeOut.add(idDoLL);

              // IF WE RELEASE THIS FOR, EVERYTHING WORKS FINE

                                /*for(i = 1; i < listIntercedeOut.size(); i++) {
                                }*/
                    }
                } else if (inicio && listIntercedeIn.contains(4) && listIntercedeIn.contains(0)) {
                    listIntercedeIn.remove(Integer.valueOf(4));
                    listIntercedeIn.remove(Integer.valueOf(idDoLL));


                } else if (!inicio && listIntercedeOut.contains(4) && listIntercedeOut.contains(0)) {

     // IF WE DISABLE THE FOLLOWING 2 LINES, EVERYTHING WORKS FINE

                    listIntercedeOut.remove(Integer.valueOf(4));
                    listIntercedeOut.remove(Integer.valueOf(0));
                }
            }
                break;
        }
    }
}

private boolean intercede (String horario1, String horario2, String horario3, String horario4){
    String[] hm1 = horario1.split(":");
    int horas1 = Integer.parseInt(hm1[0]);
    int minutos1 = Integer.parseInt(hm1[1]);
    int ms1 = (horas1 * 3600000) + (minutos1 * 60000);

    String[] hm2 = horario2.split(":");
    int horas2 = Integer.parseInt(hm2[0]);
    int minutos2 = Integer.parseInt(hm2[1]);
    int ms2 = (horas2 * 3600000) + (minutos2 * 60000);

    String[] hm3 = horario3.split(":");
    int horas3 = Integer.parseInt(hm3[0]);
    int minutos3 = Integer.parseInt(hm3[1]);
    int ms3 = (horas3 * 3600000) + (minutos3 * 60000);

    String[] hm4 = horario4.split(":");
    int horas4 = Integer.parseInt(hm4[0]);
    int minutos4 = Integer.parseInt(hm4[1]);
    int ms4 = (horas4 * 3600000) + (minutos4 * 60000);

    return (ms1<ms3 && ms3<ms2) || (ms1<ms4 && ms4<ms2);
}
}
```

add_disciplina_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCheck"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CHECK LIST"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Could anyone please explain me what is going on here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are maybe some value of your sparseSeg list who match your third condition loop . Put some log to see what's happen:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sparseSeg.size(); i++) {
                String[] hs = sparseSeg.valueAt(i).split("/");
                int idDoLL = sparseSeg.keyAt(i);
                if ((inicio && !hs[1].equals("vazio") && intercede(hs[0], hs[1], time, time2)) ||
                        (!inicio && !hs[1].equals("vazio") && intercede(time, time2, hs[0], hs[1]))) {
                    if (inicio) { // DO SOMETHING
                    } else {
                        // SHOULD ALWAYS END HERE //
                        listIntercedeOut.add(4);
                        listIntercedeOut.add(idDoLL);

                        Log.i("1 CONDITION", i + "");
              // IF WE RELEASE THIS FOR, EVERYTHING WORKS FINE

                                /*for(i = 1; i < listIntercedeOut.size(); i++) {
                                }*/
                    }
                } else if (inicio && listIntercedeIn.contains(4) && listIntercedeIn.contains(0)) {
                    listIntercedeIn.remove(Integer.valueOf(4));
                    listIntercedeIn.remove(Integer.valueOf(idDoLL));

                    Log.i("2 CONDITION", i + "");

                } else if (!inicio && listIntercedeOut.contains(4) && listIntercedeOut.contains(0)) {

     // IF WE DISABLE THE FOLLOWING 2 LINES, EVERYTHING WORKS FINE

                    listIntercedeOut.remove(Integer.valueOf(4));
                    listIntercedeOut.remove(Integer.valueOf(0));

                    Log.i("3 CONDITION", i + "");
                }
            }
```

I think at least one value match to the last condition so, your values or remove from your list.
You should maybe rework your loop system condition.

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my poor english.

(I did a little correction)

Comment: But if I "release" that for() that is commented, the values are put in the list... So it is reaching that very condition =(

Comment: Actually, you were right, the first loop has gone to CONDITION 1, and the second to CONDITION 3... That `for()` in the middle has changed the i=0 value in the first loop and didn't make it to the second... Thank you very much (:

Comment: You are welcome :)

If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and doing a up vote. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.